# Issues displaying data from a PHP script on HTML 5 webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am attempting to display the result of the PHP script on my webpage. To make sure that it actually works and recieves the data. Currently this isn't working. I have code in 3 seperate files that is supposed to handle this.

index.html

```
<div id="infoBoks">
  <section>
    <h1> Informasjon </h1>
    <p id="parkInfo">test</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1> Innstillinger </h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

script/javascript.js

```
var source = new EventSource("script/hent-status.php");
source.onmessage = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('parkInfo').innerHTML += e.data + "<br>";
};
```

The PHP file has 3 different outputs: time, frequency and data. The data variable is a hardcoded array that is a part of a function that grabs a randomized index from the array. data[random] is then what is supposed to be returned with the script. The data is also supposed to be refreshed after a certain time, decided by the frequency variable. The PHP file is provided as a part of the project I'm currently working on. Currently I'm unsure where to proceed from this, seeing as i would expect this code to work based on the theory material I've been through.

*Note: The PHP file is also placed within the script folder. 
*Note: Yes, there is a reference to the javascript file within index.html. There is also other code in the .js file that works fine with the .html file.

Edit* included hent-status.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

function sendMelding($id, $beskjed, $frekvens){
echo "retry: $frekvens" . PHP_EOL;
echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
echo "data: $beskjed" . PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;
ob_flush();
flush();    
}

$serverTime = time();
$beskjed = hentTidspunkt($serverTime);
if (isset($_GET['t'])){
    $frekvens = $_GET['t'];
}
else {
    $frekvens = 5;
}
sendMelding($serverTime, $beskjed, $frekvens*1000);

function hentTidspunkt(){
    $data = array(
            "P1,35,50;P2,10,10;P3,25,150;P4,75,250", 
            "P1,38,50;P2,9,10;P3,30,150;P4,89,250", 
            "P1,39,50;P2,10,10;P3,35,150;P4,95,250", 
            "P1,34,50;P2,8,10;P3,45,150;P4,109,250", 
            "P1,33,50;P2,6,10;P3,55,150;P4,150,250", 
            "P1,30,50;P2,4,10;P3,65,150;P4,175,250", 
            "P1,23,50;P2,3,10;P3,65,150;P4,175,250", 
            "P1,43,50;P2,2,10;P3,65,150;P4,225,250", 
            "P1,12,50;P2,5,10;P3,50,150;P4,225,250", 
            "P1,15,50;P2,6,10;P3,80,150;P4,225,250", 
            "P1,16,50;P2,6,10;P3,100,150;P4,225,250", 
            "P1,25,50;P2,7,10;P3,150,150;P4,200,250", 
            "P1,24,50;P2,7,10;P3,149,150;P4,225,250", 
            "P1,18,50;P2,4,10;P3,149,150;P4,250,250", 
            "P1,11,50;P2,3,10;P3,115,150;P4,245,250", 
            "P1,45,50;P2,7,10;P3,70,150;P4,244,250", 
            "P1,45,50;P2,5,10;P3,60,150;P4,244,250", 
            "P1,45,50;P2,5,10;P3,50,150;P4,200,250", 
            "P1,45,50;P2,7,10;P3,40,150;P4,200,250", 
            "P1,50,50;P2,10,10;P3,140,150;P4,200,250"
        );
$tilfeldig = rand(0,count($data)-1);
return $data[$tilfeldig]; 
}
?>
```